# Best practices for Spring boot testing against authenticated remote system

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, junit, credentials

I have written code that leverages [Azure SDK for Blobs](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.14.1/jar) in order to interact with the blob storage.

As a clever and dutiful developer, I have **not** tested my code by navigating the *live* application, but rather created a Spring Boot JUnit test and spent a few hours fixing all my mistakes. I didn't use anyh kind of mocking, in fact, as my problem was using the library the correct way. I ran the code against a **live** instance of a blob storage and checked that all my Java methods worked as expected.

I am writing here because

- To call it a day, I hardcoded the credentials in my source files. The repository is a company-private repository, not that harm. Credentials can be rotated, developers can all access from Azure portal and get the credentials. But still I don't like the idea of pushing credentials into code
- Having these junit tests work on Azure DevOps pipelines *could* be some of a good idea

I know from the very beginning that hardcoding credentials into code is a worst practice, but since this morning I wanted to focus on my task. Now I want to adopt the *best* practices. I am asking about redesigning the test structure

Testing code is this.

The code creates an ephemeral container and tries to store/retrieve/delete blobs. It uses a GUID to create a unique private workspace, to clear after test is finished.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = FileRepositoryServiceAzureBlobImplTest.class)
@SpringBootConfiguration
@TestConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "azure-storage-container-name:amlcbackendjunit",
        "azure-storage-connection-string:[not going to post it on Stackoverflow before rotating it]"
})
class FileRepositoryServiceAzureBlobImplTest {

    private static final Resource LOREM_IPSUM = new ClassPathResource("loremipsum.txt", FileRepositoryServiceAzureBlobImplTest.class);
    private FileRepositoryServiceAzureBlobImpl uut;
    private BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient;
    private String loremChecksum;

    @Value("${azure-storage-connection-string}")
    private String azureConnectionString;
    @Value("${azure-storage-container-name}")
    private String azureContainerName;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() throws IOException {

        String containerName = azureContainerName + "-" + UUID.randomUUID();
        blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .httpLogOptions(new HttpLogOptions().setApplicationId("az-sp-sb-aml"))
                .clientOptions(new ClientOptions().setApplicationId("az-sp-sb-aml"))
                .connectionString(azureConnectionString)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient()
        ;


        blobContainerClient.create();
        uut = spy(new FileRepositoryServiceAzureBlobImpl(blobContainerClient));
        try (InputStream loremIpsumInputStream = LOREM_IPSUM.getInputStream();) {
            loremChecksum = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(loremIpsumInputStream);
        }

        blobContainerClient
                .getBlobClient("fox.txt")
                .upload(BinaryData.fromString("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));

    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach() throws IOException {
        blobContainerClient
                .delete();
    }

    @Test
    void store_ok() {
        String desiredFileName = "loremIpsum.txt";


        FileItemDescriptor output = assertDoesNotThrow(() -> uut.store(LOREM_IPSUM, desiredFileName));
        assertAll(
                () -> assertThat(output, is(notNullValue())),
                () -> assertThat(output, hasProperty("uri", hasToString(Matchers.startsWith("azure-blob://")))),
                () -> assertThat(output, hasProperty("size", equalTo(LOREM_IPSUM.contentLength()))),
                () -> assertThat(output, hasProperty("checksum", equalTo(loremChecksum))),
                () -> {
                    String localPart = substringAfter(output.getUri().toString(), "azure-blob://");
                    assertAll(
                            () -> assertTrue(blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(localPart).exists())
                    );
                }
        );
    }

}
```

**In production** (but also in SIT/UAT), the real Spring Boot application will get the configuration from the Container environment, including the storage connection string. Yes, for this kind of test I could also avoid using Spring and `@TestPropertySource`, because I'm not leveraging any bean from the context.

### Question

I want to ask how can I amend this test in order to

1. Decouple the connection string from code
2. Softly-ignore the test if for some reason the connection string is not present (e.g. developer downloaded the project the first time and wants to kick-start) (note 1)
3. Integrate this test (with a working connection string) from Azure DevOps pipelines, where I can configure virtually any environment variable and such

Here is the build job comprised of tests

```yaml
          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Build with Gradle
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              gradleOptions: -Xmx3072m $(gradleJavaProperties)
              options: -Pci=true -PbuildId=$(Build.BuildId) -PreleaseType=${{parameters.releaseType}}
              jdkVersionOption: 1.11
              jdkArchitectureOption: x64
              publishJUnitResults: true
              sqAnalysisEnabled: true
              sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: specify
              sqGradlePluginVersion: 3.2.0
              testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
              tasks: clean build
```

Note 1: the live application **can** be kick-started without the storage connection string. It falls back to a local temporary directory.

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Comment: I should post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a bit complex to explain, so I did my best

## TL;DR

Note that the original variable names are redacted and YMMV if you try to recreate the example with the exact keys I used

- Create a secret pipeline variable containing the connection string, and bury* it into the pipeline

Example name `testStorageAccountConnectionString`

[image: Pipeline variables]

- Change the Gradle task

```yaml
              - task: Gradle@3
                displayName: Build with Gradle
                inputs:
                  gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
                  gradleOptions: -Xmx10240m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -DAZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
                  options: --build-cache -Pci=true -PgitCommitId=$(Build.SourceVersion) -PbuildId=$(Build.BuildId) -Preckon.stage=${{parameters.versionStage}} -Preckon.scope=${{parameters.versionScope}}
                  jdkVersionOption: 1.11
                  jdkArchitectureOption: x64
                  publishJUnitResults: true
                  sqAnalysisEnabled: true
                  sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: specify
                  sqGradlePluginVersion: 3.2.0
                  testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
                  tasks: clean build
                env:
                 AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: $(testStorageAccountConnectionString)
```

## Explanation

- Spring Boot accepts placeholder `${azure.storageConnectionString}` from an environment variable `AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING`. **Please read [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)** and try it locally first. This means we need to run the test with an environment variable propely set in order to resolve the placeholder
- Gradle can run with `-D` to add an environment variable. `-DAZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)` adds an environment variable `AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING` to the test run equal to the **pipeline environment variable** `AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING` (not that fantasy)
- Azure DevOps pipelines protect secret variables from unwanted access. We created the pipeline variable as secret, so there is another trick to do first

Gradle's **env** attributes set environment variable for the pipeline container. In this case, we make sure that Gradle runs with `AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING` set to `testStorageAccountConnectionString`. Env is the only place where Azure pipelines agent will resolve and set free the content of the secret variable

- Secrets cannot be retrieved any more from web interface. Azure Pipelines are designed for this